# Using Material Icons with Styled Components

Tags: styled-components

Just started playing around with Styled Components. Is there a way to style third party icons such as Material Design Icons? This is the code I have so far but obviously it isn't working. **Relavant code is below Content component** Thanks!

```
const MaterialIcon = (props) => <i className="material-icons">account_balance</i>;

const Icon = styled(MaterialIcon)`
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
`;

const CheckThisOut = props => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Header>
      <h5>{props.title}</h5>
      <Icon />
    </Header>
    <Divider />
    <Content>
      <p>5% of all participants in this campaign were first time users.</p>
    </Content>
  </Wrapper>
);

export default CheckThisOut;
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `styled(AnyComp)` notation to work `AnyComp` needs to accept the incoming `className` prop and attach it to a DOM node.

For your example to work `MaterialIcon` has to use the passed in `className`, otherwise the styles are injected but no DOM node is targeted:

```
const MaterialIcon = (props) => (
  <i className={`material-icons ${props.className}`}>account_balance</i>
);

// WORKS 
const Icon = styled(MaterialIcon)`
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
`;
```

See our [documentation page about styling any component](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components) for more information!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but here's another way to write it as a single expression. Using styled components' `.attrs()` ([see docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props)) for the class name and the CSS `::after` selector for the icon name.

```
const ThumbUp = styled.i.attrs(() => ({ className: "material-icons" }))`
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  &:after {
    content: "thumb_up";
  }
`;
```

Writing this in a more generic way will allow you to use it for any of the available icons. This makes use of styled component ability to adapt based on props (see [styled components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) for more info).

```
const MaterialIcon = styled.i.attrs(() => ({ className: "material-icons" }))`
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  &:after {
    content: ${props => props.iconName || "help"};
  }
`;
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
<MaterialIcon iconName="check" />
```