# Use Material Icon along with Styled-Components in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, google-material-icons

I am trying to style the material icon in my react app using google material icon webapi.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971742/using-material-icons-with-styled-components) but it is not working. The icon is showing but the style I am applying to it is not working. They are not even showing when I inspect them.
I want to give it a position absolute and move it around.

```
      const ArrowIcon = (props) => (
         <i className="material-icons-outlined"> {props.icon} </i>
      );
    
      const LeftBtn  =  styled(ArrowIcon)`
      position:absolute;
      font-size:100px;
      `;
      const RightBtn = styled(ArrowIcon)``;

return ( 
     <LeftBtn icon = {"arrow_back"} />
        <RightBtn icon = {"arrow_forward"}/> 
  )
```

EDIT: i just found the answer that worked for me ... here is the link , it was just below the method i was trying before.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66222892/8680919

Answer (score 0):

You suppose [to pass the `className` prop in order to inject the generated `className` from CSS in JS](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components):

```
const ArrowIcon = (props) => (
  <i className={classNames("material-icons-outlined", props.className)}>
    {props.icon}
  </i>
);
```

Comment: not working, PS. i want to give it a position absolute and move it around. The icon is visible on screen but not taking css properties in LeftBtn or RightBtn

Comment: I also want to add , onClick is also not working on LeftBtn and RightBtn. I am new to styled-Components. I really dont understand whats wrong i am doing here /n EDIT- i did a workaround for onClick like this `  const ArrowIcon = (props) => (
     <i className="material-icons-outlined" onClick = {props.handle}> {props.icon} </i>
  );`